# How do I plot my histogram for density rather than count? (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

I have a data frame called 'train' with a column 'string' and a column 'string length' and a column 'rank' which has ranking ranging from 0-4.

I want to create a histogram of the string length for each ranking and plot all of the histograms on one graph to compare. I am experiencing two issues with this:

The only way I can manage to do this is by creating separate datasets e.g. with the following type of code:

```
S0 = train.loc[train['rank'] == 0]
S1 = train.loc[train['rank'] == 1]
```

Then I create individual histograms for each dataset using:

```
plt.hist(train['string length'], bins = 100)
plt.show()
```

This code doesn't plot the density but instead plots the counts. How do I alter my code such that it plots density instead?

Is there also a way to do this without having to create separate datasets? I was told that my method is 'unpythonic'

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you feel that I am missing any relevant information that needs to be added to my question?

Comment: An ideal question is where the code can simply be copied to reproduce the problem. Your question lacks the dataset and the minimal code to do so. If one wants to play with the code, one can't

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: Does adding the `density=True` keyword not do what you want?

Comment: Hi Ed, yes it does! I'm still not sure how to do this without creating 5 new DataFrames though :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'string'].groupby('rank').hist(density=True, bins =10, figsize=(5,5))
```

Basically, what it does is select all columns except `string`, group them by `rank` and make an histogram of all them following the arguments.

The density argument set to `density=True` draws it in a normalized manner, as

Hope this has helped.

**EDIT**:

f there are more variables and you want the histograms overlapped, try:

```
df.groupby('rank')['string length'].hist(density=True, histtype='step', bins =10,figsize=(5,5))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried this method but this seems to be giving me a histogram for every column in my data rather than a histogram for every rank. It is also plotting the histograms on separate graphs rather than overlapping them.

Comment: My apologies. If there are more variables and you want the histograms overlapped, try:

`df.groupby('rank')['string length'].hist(density=True, histtype='step', bins =10,figsize=(5,5))`

Comment: I have added it as an edit of the main answer so everyone can see it.